# HTTP Strict Transport Security (HSTS)Errors and Warnings, Can you check the attachment? How can I fixed this

Tags: php, html, css, apache, hsts

I used this code :

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
...
Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains"
...
</VirtualHost>
```

```
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains; preload
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=0; includeSubDomains
```

How can remove to  `max-age = 0;`

> Error:
> Strict-Transport-Security header appears more than once. (İn google browser)

Resolution:
Send only one. But, I cant fixed.

Note: it's working right in the local. (Only one --> max- age = 31536000).

Comment: The first one seems to be set in default ssl virtual host. Second one is propably set in virtual host of specific domain, by htaccess or even dynamicly by your software. Personally, I would check in the order I listed.

Comment: I checked, everything looks good. Strict-Transport-Security header appears  once  in local.  where get max = 0 ; in live

Answer (score 0):

try deleting: Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=0; includeSubDomains

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).